# Picasso is enlarging imageview size on tablet

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I have used following code to set image in imageview.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(authorModel.getImageUrl()).placeholder(resourceId).error(resourceId).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(authorImageView);

 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_author_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder_author"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/item_course_title_view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

But Picasso is not using original imageview size while loading on tablet. It is enlarging image.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: remove scale type in imageview

Comment: @RanjanDas Its not working

Comment: use resize method with picasso.

Comment: Your imageview doesn't have any dimensions anyways.

Comment: @ChintanSoni It can use size of image set in src

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

It will enlarge the image size.

Answer (score 0):

Imageview resize as programatically use this below code

```
ImageView img_view= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_view);
int width = 60;
int height = 60;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
img_view.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set scale type with Picasso and remove scale type in ImageView.

```
Picasso  
.with(context)
.load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[0])
.fit()
// call .centerInside() or .centerCrop() to avoid a stretched image
.into(imageViewFit);
```

here is the link for scaling image in [picasso.](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit)